# Resource pool MTBF MTTR

Tags: java, anylogic

I want to simulate the maintenance of a machine in  production line, for this I've set the resource block with a weibull distribution for the time next to failure( that rapresent the time between failure) and time to repair. Right now i would know the mean time of the  time next to failure and time to repair, I understood that I must to set two different variable but i don't know how can express the average in anylogic

Answer (score 0):

You would normally use the "Statistics" object from the palette.

Just add values to it when you have them, i.e. `myStatsObject.add(myNewValue)` and you can get various stats about all data you added.

See the [help](https://anylogic.help/anylogic/analysis/statistics.html) for more info.

Comment: sorry, i don't understand what is it myStasObject, for you, is like a function or it's refered to a block like service?

Comment: Name your Statistics object `myStatsObject` and give it some value `myNewValue`. Check the help and example models on how it is used :)